# Finding the largest K elements in a list with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1D `numpy` array of numbers. I want to find the largest k elements in that array along with their indices. How can I do that with `numpy`? If this is not possible to do with `numpy`, then what's the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Indeed very probably a duplicate of that question. The solution is to use `numpy.argsort(arr)[::-1][:k]`, which yields the required indices.

Comment: @eickenberg: or `argpartition` (see answer that I just posted under the other question).

Comment: Nice. And with that it works in linear time then. This business of sorting the whole array has always bugged me, but I have never been in the situation where the efficacy of this operation was crucial, so I never looked further. Thanks for this.